# Biblatex / biber code stopped working

Tags: biblatex, biber

This piece of code has recently started to flag errors having never done so before.  The error is

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d. ...\addcomma\addspace #1\addcomma\addspace #4 (followed by: })
```

and code is:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
      {#1\addcomma\addspace #4\addcomma\isdot}
      {#1\addcomma\addspace #4}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
      {\addcomma\addspace #1\addcomma\addspace #4}
      {\addcomma\addspace\bibstring{and} #1\addcomma\addspace #4\addcomma\isdot}%
    }%
```

Any reason why this should now be happening please and how should I fix it?

Comment: See [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864). What exactly do you seek to achieve with that code? There should be less intrusive ways to get a `family-given` name format and an "and" before the last author.

Comment: The code is a legacy from this question, which justifies the intrusiveness:http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146870/4954

Comment: I just saw that, hang on for a bit, there *must* be an easier way.

Comment: So the only thing you are missing from a default with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} ` say is the last comma after the last author (before the year)?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `biblatex` standard styles and version 3.5 you could get what you asked for in [punctuation after authors/editors in bib latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146841/35864) with the two lines

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} 
\DeclareDelimFormat[biblist,bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Unfortunately, `biblatex-philosophy` doesn't as of now use these fancy new features, we will have to enable them ourselves. We have just changed `\addspace` for `\printdelim{nameyeardelim}`/`\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}` at the appropriate places. (Note that the macros from `biblatex-classic.bbx` are almost exact copies of their counterparts in `authoryear.bbx` with support for `nameaddon` added.)

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }%
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
       {\bibnamedash}%
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{nameaddon}{}%
          {\setunit{\addspace}%
           \printtext[brackets]{\printfield{nameaddon}}}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}%
          {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}%
       {}%
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}%


\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }%
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
       {\bibnamedash}%
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}%
```

From which point on the two lines from above do exactly the right thing.

MWE (adapted from [punctuation after authors/editors in bib latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146841/35864))

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-classic, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, natbib=true, backend=biber, indexing=true, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

 % Bibliography customisation
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\adddot\nopunct\isdot}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \printtext{\bibstring{In}\addcolon\space}%
}

% Remove parentheses from year
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
      \begingroup%
        \clearfield{month}%
        \clearfield{day}%
    \ifboolexpr{%
      test {\iffieldundef{date}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{year}}
    }%
      {\iftoggle{bbx:nodate}{\printtext{%
        \midsentence\bibstring{nodate}}}{}}%
      {\printtext{\printdateextra}}%
       \endgroup}%

% Dot after year
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\adddot\space}

% Put number in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[biblist]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }%
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
       {\bibnamedash}%
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{nameaddon}{}%
          {\setunit{\addspace}%
           \printtext[brackets]{\printfield{nameaddon}}}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}%
          {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}%
       {}%
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}%


\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }%
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
       {\bibnamedash}%
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}%

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,aksin,geer,worman,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: page three - the bibliography - of the MWE]

Comment: A very instructive answer!

Comment: Agreed, @moewe is really quite the expert on the latest `biblatex` features.